# Cholesky Factor and matrix 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a positive definite matrix and $L$ be the Cholesky factor such that $M=LL^T$, then $$||M||_2=||L||_2^2$$ For this problem I already have one side of the inequality, i.e, $$||M||_2=||LL^T||_2\leq||L||_2||L^T||_2=||L||_2||L||_2=||L||_2^2$$ So $||M||_2\leq ||L||_2^2$.

However now I am having trouble getting the 2nd side. I tried to use equivalent definitions for the 2-norm and try to deduce from that but cant seem to get it. Any hints or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is true because $\max_{\|u\|=1}\|Mu\|_2=\max_{\|u\|=1}|u^TMu|$ whenever $M$ is real symmetric. You may orthogonally diagonalise $M$ to see it. Now the LHS is $\|M\|_2$ and the RHS is $\|L\|_2^2$.